# Get Request URL within Startup.auth in Asp.net web application

Tags: asp.net, auth0

We implemented Auth0 login mechanism in our Asp.Net web application. This application is hosted in our test environment and working. As part of our application this website has to access externally as well means outside the respective network.So we do have the extenal URL configured for this website. Now inside oour code we need to have a condition that if the user is requested through this external url then the callback url should be like external url else the normal url within the network. We have web config keys for the same as below:

```
<add key="auth0:RedirectUri" value="http://localhost:8080/callback" />
<add key="auth0:externalUri" value="https://abc/callback" />
```

To identify which URL is requested, there is a code added inside `Startup.auth.cs` file:

```
private string XcagRedirectURI
{
    get
    {
        string requestStringLower = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString().ToLower();
        if (requestStringLower.Contains("abc.com"))
        {
            return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["auth0:externalUri"];
        }
        else
        {
            return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["auth0:RedirectUri"];
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is the request URL always returning to us "http://127.0.0.1/". So the condition always executes else part. We tried different options but all returns same URI. Any suggessions?

Regards
Sangeetha